# Why does axios always send empty object?

Tags: javascript, php, axios

I'm trying to figure this out and it's driving me mad. I am trying to send an object of data using an axios post request. It goes to the file okay but the object is always empty. So when I use this code:

```
axios.post('php/send_email.php', {
  params: {
    name: 'niall'
  }
})
.then(function (result) {

  console.log(result)

});
```

And then use the php below:

```
<?php
  echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

It will always output an error of name being undefined for the result from the http request.Can anyone shed some light on this and where I am going wrong?

Also I noticed that this seems to be a problem with sending an object because when I try:

```
axios.post('php/send_email.php', 'niall' )
.then(function (result) {
  console.log(result)
});
```

And then print out the array using:

```
<?php
 print_r($_POST);
?>
```

It will show:

> Object {data: "Array↵(↵    [niall] => ↵)↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}

Comment: I figured it out eventually. Please see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460761/axios-http-always-returns-with-empty-data/41461236?noredirect=1#comment70134748_41461236

Answer (score 0):

Try sending like this

```
axios.post('php/send_email.php', { name: 'niall' }})
```

instead of wrapping parameters in an extra `params` object.

Comment: Still name is undefined. :-(

Comment: Ye it gives this: Object {data: "Array↵(↵)↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}

Comment: But that is an empty array. The data is an empty array. There is no name parameter in it.

Comment: Thanks for the help though. I'll post here if I ever get it fixed.

Comment: You are welcome :) and with patience, can you print the same using `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. both will gives us same. but just checking

Comment: Ye same empty array. Object {data: "array(0) {↵}↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object…}

Comment: I've discovered that it does not convert your data into query string. It just sends your data "as is". Just try `axios.post('php/send_email.php', 'name=niall')` and it works. And yes, this behavior does not match the documented one...